Is there a good way to BatchMapping or use Data Loaders in Spring GraphQL utilising non-exposed fields?
Consider the below minimal GQL schema:
type query {
    appointments: [Appointment!]!
}

type Appointment {
    id: ID!
    job: Job!
}

type Company {
    id: ID!
    job: Job!
}

type Job {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

and the below minimal Kotlin classes:
data class Appointment(
    val id: String,
    val jobId: JobId,
)

data class Company(
    val id: String,
    val jobId: JobId,
)

data class JobId(val id: String)

data class Job(
    val id: JobId,
    val name: String,
)

that would have lot more properties, and imagine there are also 10+ more classes that have this construct of having a val jobId: JobId property.
Is there a way to resolve that jobId for any kind of entity that exists, in an easy way and following DRY?
Considering I have access to a method fun JobIdFetcher.getJobsByIds(jobIds: List<String>): Map<String, Job>, I was hoping to be able to do something like
    @BatchMapping(field = "job", typename="jobId")
    fun job(jobIds: List<JobId>): Map<JobId, Job> {
        return JobIdFetcher.getJobsByIds(jobIds)
    }

but this doesn't work, as it doesn't associate that the Appointment and Company classes have the jobId property and that it should be resolved using the above.
Is there anything that could enable me to do this without changing the schema?
If not, I guess I might end up duplicating lots of code by writing something like
    @BatchMapping(typeName = "Appointment", field = "job")
    fun batchJobsForAppointments(appointments: List<Appointment>): Map<Appointment, Job> {
        return batchResolveJobs(appointments)
    }

    @BatchMapping(typeName = "Company", field = "job")
    fun batchJobsForCompany(companies: List<Company>): Map<Company, Job> {
        return batchResolveJobs(companies)
    }

    private fun <T : JobHolder> batchResolveJobs(jobHolders: List<T>): Map<T, Job> {
        val jobIds = jobHolders.map { it.jobId }
        val jobs = JobIdFetcher.getJobsByIds(jobIds)
        return jobHolders.associateWith { jobHolder ->
            jobs[jobHolder.jobId] ?: throw RuntimeException("Job not found")
        }
    }

interface JobHolder {
    val jobId: JobId
}

with Appointment, Company and all other classes implementing this interface and having separate resolution methods.

Spring for GraphQL offers the @BatchMapping approach for some use cases, but here registering a BatchLoader directly against the registry:
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    public MyConfig(BatchLoaderRegistry registry) {

        registry.forTypePair(JobId.class, Job.class).registerMappedBatchLoader((jobIds, env) -> {
                // return Mono<Map<JobId, Job>
        });

    }

}

See the Spring for GraphQL reference documentation for more.

This by itself doesn't seem to work; check this gist: https://gist.github.com/AlexiosP/e240d2374c8592f18c8bd893ef6f5d3f
